# Can't access to a collection from a looped collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to access to a collection inside another collection in a for loop. 
Is it possible? I'm getting an error at the 4th line `Error getting documents TypeError: cookUser is not a function`

```
var mealsOnline = [];
return db.collection('users').get().then(function (snapshot) {
   snapshot.forEach(cookUser => {
      cookUser.collection('meals').get().then(function (snapshot2) {
         snapshot2.forEach(meal => {
            if (meal.data().portion > 0) {
               var mealObject = meal.data();
               mealObject.id = meal.id;
               mealObject.address = cookUser.data().address;
               mealObject.cookName = cookUser.data().displayName;
               mealsOnline.push(mealObject);
            }
         });
      });
   });
   return Promise.all(mealsOnline);
}).catch(err => {
   console.log('Error getting documents', err);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `forEach()` [method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#forEach), your `cookUser` object is a [QueryDocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot).

As detailed in the documentation (link above), "QueryDocumentSnapshot offers the same API surface as a DocumentSnapshot". Therefore you should use the [ref](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#~ref) abstract type of a [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot), as follows:

```
   snapshot.forEach(cookUser => {
      cookUser.ref.collection('meals').get().then(snapshot2 => {
        .....
      })
   })
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#forEach